# Where does Google App Engine/Java SDK store records and blobs?

Tags: java, windows, sdk, google-cloud-datastore

Where does the **SDK** for Google App Engine/Java store records and blobs?

I am specifically interested in the Windows SDK.

I would like to see and clear out data, during both manual and automated testing.

Ideally, there would also be a trimmed down version of the admin console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by default, the java app engine sdk stores blobs in your app's `WEB-INF/appengine-generated/` subdirectory and datastore records in the `local_db.bin` file in that directory.

you can change these by setting the `datastore.backing_store` and `blobstore.backing_store` java properties (see [`LocalBlobstoreService.BACKING_STORE_PROPERTY`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.LocalBlobstoreService.BACKING_STORE_PROPERTY)
and [`LocalDatastoreService.BACKING_STORE_PROPERTY`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.BACKING_STORE_PROPERTY)).

as for trimmed down admin console, [there is one](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#The_Development_Console), similar to the python sdk's. start the java development server and go to http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin.